# No EVENT named markup://c:RedirectOpportunityEvent found : [markup://c:HIC_EditOppProducts]

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Getting this error when trying to deploy, any idea why?

```
<aura:component controller="HIC_EditOppProductsController" implements="force:hasRecordId,lightning:actionOverride,lightning:hasPageReference,force:lightningQuickAction">
    <aura:attribute name="LineItemList" type="list"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordTypeName" type="string" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="string" default="" /> 
    <aura:attribute name="Spinner" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" />
    <aura:registerEvent name="RedirectOpportunityEvent" type="c:RedirectOpportunityEvent"/>

    <div>
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered" style="width:100%">
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.recordTypeName == 'Advertiser_Direct'}">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                        <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Product Name">Product Name</div></th>
                        <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Budget">Budget</div></th>
                        <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Start Date">Start Date</div></th>
                        <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="End Date">End Date</div></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.LineItemList}" var="item" indexVar="index">
                        <tr class="slds-hint-parent">                        
                            <td><lightning:select aura:id="validateFields" disabled="{!if(item.Product2.Name != null, true,false)}" name="select1" label="Select Product Name" value="{!item.Product_Name__c}" required="true">
                                <option value="">choose one...</option>
                                <option value="Micro Cast">Micro Cast</option>
                                <option value="Surround unit">Surround unit</option>
                            </lightning:select>
           <!--             <lightning:input disabled="{!if(item.Product2.Name != null, true,false)}" aura:id="validateFields" type="text" value="{!item.Product2.Name}" label="Product Name"/>   -->
                            </td>
                            <td><lightning:input aura:id="validateFields" type="number" formatter="currency" step="0.01" required="true" value="{!item.Budget__c}" label="Budget"/></td>
                            <td><lightning:input aura:id="validateFields" type="date" required="true" value="{!item.Start_Date__c}" label="Start Date"/></td>
                            <td><lightning:input  aura:id="validateFields" type="date" value="{!item.End_Date__c}" label="End Date" required="true"/></td>
                            <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close" size="large" variant="bare" onclick="{!c.handleRemoveItem}" alternativeText="Close" class="slds-button_icon-inverse" value="{!index}"/>  
                        </tr>

                    </aura:iteration>
                </tbody>
            </aura:if>
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.recordTypeName == 'Publisher'}">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                        <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Product Name">Product Name</div></th>
                        <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Monthly Revenue">Monthly Revenue</div></th>
                        <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="#Months">#Months</div></th>
                        <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Start Date">Start Date</div></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.LineItemList}" var="item" indexVar="index">
                        <tr class="slds-hint-parent">                        
                            <td><lightning:select name="select2" disabled="{!if(item.Product2.Name != null, true,false)}" label="Select Product Name" aura:id="validateFields" required="true" value="{!item.Product_Name__c}">
                                <option value="">choose one...</option>
                                <option value="SAAS Fee">SAAS Fee</option>
                                <option value="One Time Fee">One Time Fee</option>
                            </lightning:select>
     <!--                   <lightning:input disabled="true" aura:id="validateFields" type="text" value="{!item.Product2.Name}" label="Product Name"/>   -->
                            </td>
                            <td><lightning:input type="number" aura:id="validateFields" formatter="currency" step="0.01" required="true" value="{!item.Budget__c}" label="Monthly Revenue"/></td>
                            <td><lightning:input type="number" aura:id="validateFields" required="true" value="{!item.Quantity}" label="#Months"/></td>
                            <td><lightning:input type="date" aura:id="validateFields" required="true" value="{!item.Start_Date__c}" label="Start Date"/></td>
                            <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close" size="large" variant="bare" onclick="{!c.handleRemoveItem}" alternativeText="Close" class="slds-button_icon-inverse" value="{!index}"/>  
                        </tr>

                    </aura:iteration>
                </tbody>
            </aura:if>
        </table>
        <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Add Line Item" title="Add Line Item" onclick="{!c.addNewRow}" class="temclass"/>   
        <lightning:button variant="Success" class="slds-button" label="SAVE" onclick="{!c.handleSubmit}"/>
    </div>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.Spinner}">
        <div class="exampleHolder">
            <div class="demo-only demo-only demo-only_viewport demo--inverse" style="height:100%">
                <div class="slds-spinner_container slds-is-fixed">
                    <div role="status" class="slds-spinner slds-spinner_medium">
                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
                        <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
                        <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an (unnamed type) event of type: `c:RedirectOpportunityEvent`

Add this new event and your component will deploy.

Something like:

```
<!--can be APPLICATION or COMPONENT it's not clear from the component code you'll have to determine this from where you dispatch the event-->
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="Event template" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="data" type="Object" />
```

Note, you don't need the data (or any) attribute at all, but I typically include something like this so you can pass arbitrary data.

To create the event in VS code, enter Cmd-Shift-P, type "Create Lightning Event" - this will then ask for an event name - in this case RedirectOpportunityEvent, then hit enter.

[image]

Or in the developer console - select Create Event and then choose the RedirectOpportunityEvent as the name:

[image]

Comment: So this,                                                                                                      <aura:registerEvent name="RedirectOpportunityEvent" type="c:RedirectOpportunityEvent"/>
<aura:event type="component" description="Event template" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="data" type="Object" />
</aura:event>
    <div>
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered" style="width:100%">
      <aura:if isTrue="{!v.recordTypeName == 'Advertiser_Direct'}">

Comment: It needs to be a separate event component. From VSCode, Cmd-Shift-P, type "Create Lightning Event" - this will then ask for an event name - in this case RedirectOpportunityEvent, then hit enter.

Comment: <aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="Event template" >
 <aura:attribute name="opportunityRecordId" type="String"/>
</aura:event>     / is currently in there

Comment: In where? In the org structure?